# Why do we define the norm on the sequence space of $\mathbb{C}$ like this?

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis

> 1.2-1 Sequence space $s$. This space consists of the set of all ( bounded or unbounded) sequences of complex numbers and the metric $d$ defined by:
>
> $$ d(x,y) = \sum_{j} \frac{1}{2^j} \frac{|\epsilon_j -\eta_j |}{ 1+ | \epsilon_j - \eta_j |}$$
>
> Where, $x= (\epsilon_j) , y=(\eta_j) \in s$
>
> Functional Analysis by Kreyszig, Wiley student edition.

Why do we define the distance between sequences in this way?

---

### My attempt:

$\epsilon_j - \eta_j$ can be thought of as the complex vector joining the $jth$ point between the two sequences. I don't quite get the idea behind the $2^j( 1+ | \epsilon_j - \eta_j |)$ in the denominator.

Comment: You haven't given us the relation between $x,y,\epsilon_i,\eta_i,$ although we can guess.

Comment: Note that the set of all complex numbers under the metric $d(u,v)=\frac{|u-v|}{1+|u-v|}$ is bounded, so the sequences are bounded *under this metric.*

Comment: Just a terminology quibble: the metric you wrote is _not_ a "norm" (in the contemporary sense), since it is not homogeneous, that is, $d(tx,ty)$ with scalar $t>0$ is rarely $t\cdot d(x,y)$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This metric is one of many possible metrics which you can put on the product $\mathbb C^n$ (where I permit $n$ to be infinity) so that it induces the product topology. There are two things happening at once in that formula: replacing a metric with a bounded one, and using those to induce a metric on the product.

We start with the usual metric $d(x,y)=|x-y|$. There are several standard ways of replacing it with an equivalent metric which is bounded (that is, is values are bounded). The one the author uses here is $d'(x,y)=\frac{d(x,y)}{1+d(x,y)}$. Another common way is $d'(x,y)=\min(d(x,y),1)$.

Now, given a sequence of metrizable topological spaces $X_n$, the product topology on $\prod_n X_n$ is also metrizable, and this sort of sum is precisely one way to do that: on each $X_n$ pick a metric $d_n$ which is bounded by $1$, and metrize the product by $d((x_n),(y_n))=\sum\frac{1}{2^n}d_n(x_n,y_n)$. Note that this boundedness is only required in the case of infinite product, to guarantee convergence. In your question we take $X_n=\mathbb C$ for each $n$, and let $d_n$ be the metric $d'$ from the previous paragraph.

Comment: ... and, indeed, the $2^{-n}$ can be replaced by any sequence $a_n$ of positive reals with finite sum... So, really, even though a countable (infinite) product of metric spaces is _metrizable_, there is no canonical metric.